# What style of bathroom facilities are in Hong Kong hotels?

Tags: hotels, hong-kong, hygiene

If I attend a conference in Hong Kong, and stay in the Sheraton Hong Kong, does it have Western style bathroom facilities (seated), or Eastern (squat)?

Comment: This question is dedicated to Gayot Fow and Hippietrail... :)

Comment: I dedicate this question to all SE members, we are all crazy about toilets...

Comment: I am a Hong Konger and I can't remember when and where I have seen a squat toilet in the city...

Comment: We should create a [tag:toilets] tag.

Comment: @MeNoTalk - of course people on an anonymous travel site are crazy about toilets. Using a toilet is something that everyone does (sometimes urgently when traveling), few people like to talk about it face to face with strangers, and no one wants to end up in a situation where they have to call the front desk clerk to ask what to do about the "deposit" accidentally left in the bidet or because they clogged the toilet with paper towels when they didn't understand local toilet customs. A little foreknowledge before traveling to know what to expect can help put the traveler at ease.

Comment: I think it is just a tube that comes out of the wall that you attach to yourself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on the hotel. Upscale ones, especially if they're western brands, will generally have western style (sit) toilets. Cheap hotels, especially if they're local or not a chain, will generally have eastern style (squat) toilets. It's easy to find your preferred style if you know where to look and can identify the clientele the hotel caters to. A large hotel might offer both styles, though I don't know of any that do.

For your specific case, the Sheraton has western style toilets, as you can see from [photo #10 in the "rooms" gallery](http://www.starwoodhotels.com/sheraton/property/photos/index.html?propertyID=482&mediaID=1028713781) (in the center of the mirror, underneath the flowers, partially obscured by the sink's reflection):

[image]

Comment: Do you have a reference or experience on the cheap hotels having squat toilets? All the cheap places I stayed (for instance in Chunking Mansions) had throne toilets. -- Though the shower head was over the toilet to save space in the tiny bathrooms.

Answer (score 14):

I have stayed at the Sheraton HK hotel (back in 2007), the one in Nathan road (that's the English name of the road if I remember correctly). The toilet is no different than any western style toilet. The hotel itself and its facilities are pretty decent.

Answer (score 12):

I have not stayed at the Sheraton specifically but based on my experience with other Hong Kong hotels/venues, I am pretty sure you will find “Western” bathrooms there.

But as far as (men's) toilet experience is concerned, in Hong Kong you must try The Peninsula, more specifically [its bar](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g294217-d1746041-r147194548-The_Bar_Peninsula-Hong_Kong.html) (you can go there even if you can't afford the hotel).

Comment: Having been there I concur it is a very interesting experience. Worth it to have a drink and watch the laser show.

Comment: Note that if you do go to the bar, dress the part. They will turn you away if you are not dressed to spec, _even if you **are** a guest in the hotel_.

Answer (score 4):

The Sheraton is above my discretionary accommodation level - but based on what is provided at less salubrious establishments, I'd expect western toilets in en suites and just maybe a squat toilet or too in shared facilities - usually well labelled on the door.

Even quite down-market Hong-Kong hotels are liable to have western-style toilets in en-suites.  As above, in shared wash-rooms with multiple toilets one or a few may be squat style.

I use single 'room with ensuite in hostel' when possible (camera gear and PC safe, OK bed, air-conditioning, internet - what else do you need? :-) ) and these essentially always  have western style toilets.

Cross the border into Shenzhen and 'your mileage may vary', with upper level hotels offering flush toilets but lower price accommodation being more likely to provide only a squatty.

Answer (score 4):

Of course it has. All mid to upscale Hotel in China do these days especially if they are name brand. Same for restaurants. The only "hole in the ground" style toilets I've seen in the last 5 years are either in very rural areas or inside the factory for operators and line workers.

Assuming you mean the Sheraton in Kowloon close to the harbor, it's really nice, if a bit dated, hotel. Haven't been there in a while but it used to have a great roof top pool with wonderful views of Victoria Harbor and Hong Kong proper. There also used to be a bar in the basement level that had beer taps build into the walls at the table with meters (like a gas station). When you sit down, they zero out the meter, bring you empty glasses and off you go (if you are into this sort of thing)